# Kubuntu installation on Minix Z83-4 (PC box based on Intel X5-Z8300 cpu and intel graphic)

Tags: boot, system-installation, xubuntu, lubuntu, kubuntu

I'm trying to install Linux in a Minix Neo Z83-4. It's a small PC box based on Intel Atom x5-Z8300 Cherry Trail with 4Gb of memory and only 32Gb of eMMC as a hard drive. The box is released with windows 10, but performs too bad with that OS and I want to move to Linux.

I like a steady and responsive OS and don't care graphic and look, so I wish to go for any LTS of kubuntu/xubuntu/lubuntu.

Did tons of tentatives to install linux in this box. I also used a script by Linuxium called isorespin.sh to adapt the official releases to Atom or Apollo CPUs and inject some additional hardware support.  But none of the distro, original or respinned, did work. Tried all k-, x-, l- LTS distro.
The pc boot any distro until the boot menu, but once I select the 'install kubuntu' the screen blanks and everything stops. Run kubuntu does the same.

There is only a release of the standard Ubuntu distributed by Minix that can boot and install the os in this box.

Unfortunately my skills with linux are limited, and after two months of experiments, now I'm short of ideas on how to procede.  I wonder if it is possible to take out parts of the working standard ubuntu ISO release and use them in a kubuntu ISO to create a working kubuntu distribution or if someone is able to suggest me a working solution.

Thanks for any help or suggestion you may give me.

Comment: Ubuntu ir any Desktop Linux does NOT perform better than Windows 10 in that crappy CPU.

Comment: This looks 95% solved: https://theminixforum.com/index.php?threads/neo-z83-4-ubuntu-18-04-01-build.227/ . Once you have Ubuntu running, the final 5% is swapping the desktop environment from Ubuntu to Kubuntu, fairly easy.

Answer (score 0):

I had install Kubuntu in my (old) Z83 and I have some video issues (youtube, VLC...). I solved it installing (and running) Lubuntu over my Kubuntu:

```
sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop
```

Some people tried with xubuntu.